# How to prevent index.ts imports (e.g. via eslint) in libraries of a monorepo?

Tags: typescript, import, eslint, monorepo, typescript-eslint

My project has about the following structure:

```
project
|-- applications
|   |-- app1
|   |-- app2
|
|-- libraries
    |-- lib1
    |   |-- src
    |   |   |-- lib
    |   |   |   |-- dom-utils.ts
    |   |   |   |-- index.ts // exporting dom-utils
    |   |   |-- components
    |   |   |   |-- Foo.ts
    |   |   |   |-- index.ts // exporting Foo
    |   |   |-- index.ts // exporting * from components and lib
    |   |-- index.ts // export * from src
    |-- lib2
```

`app1` and `app2` may import modules from `lib1` or `lib2` by means of a package import, for example:

```
import { Foo } from 'lib1';
```

That is working fine.

`Foo` or any other component within the lib however may use code within the same lib just with the complete path to the source file and not via `index.ts` resolution, since this could easily lead to cycles. Just imagine `Foo` importing `../` and `dom-utils` doing the same...

Hence I want to find a way to completely forbid importing folders (i.e. index.ts files) from within the lib itself. I already played around a bit with the different rules from `eslint-plugin-import` like `import/no-cycle`, but had no luck so far.

Note: I really want to forbid ALL `index.ts` imports within a lib, even if they may not produce a cycle.

If something is still unclear, please ask and I'll add the information :)

Comment: Can this rule help you somehow? https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports

Comment: I think I tried it, but the library is quite large and as far as I understand I would have to add every path to the pattern since excluding index.ts won't work there. By module resolution magic index.ts won't appear in the import statement.